# Define error model on auto generate swagger api

Tags: typescript, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

[image]
[image]

Hello, In the first picture, you can see the response model as `TokenViewModel` but I may take also the `ResponseErrorViewModel` which defined swagger you can see on the second picture.

My problem is type error; `Property 'errors' does not exist on type 'TokenViewModel'.`

How can I handle `ResponseErrorViewModel`?

NOTE: It's auto generated api, I don't want to touch `AuthenticationService`. The solution should be generic.